# Problems with ssh error after vm replication to connect Hadoop clusters

Tags: ssh

As a single cluster, both start-yarn.sh and start-dfs.sh saw that it turned on and off well over jps, replicated the vm currently made into a single cluster, changed the username to usermod, changed the group name to `/etc/hostname`, and changed it to static ip to nmcli.
In addition, 192.168.160.101 node01 and 192.168.160.102 node02 were added to `/etc/hosts`.

And as usual, I made a keygen in each vm and confirmed that the keygen was added to authorized_keys in this way: `ssh-copy-id node01@192.168.160.101`, `ssh-copy-id node02@192.168.160.102`.

After that, I tried to connect to ssh, but I saw that it went well to `ssh node01@192.168.160.101`

After the logout, the value entered in `/etc/hosts` is `ssh node01`, so I ask for the password

First of all, it was definitely easy to get in without a password because I don't understand asking for a password and even studying environment, so there is no reason to make a mistake by uniformizing all the passwords. Permission Dinai

The permissions of the home directory, `~/.ssh`, and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with chmod have been changed to 700,600.

Just in case, I tried `ssh 192.168.160.101`, but I can't enter.
`ssh -l node01 192.168.160.101` can enter

`Ping 192.168.160.101` Good.
`Ping -4 node 01`. Good.
`nsloopup node01` it's coming up well...

I don't know what the hell the reason is.
The `start-dhs.sh` command doesn't work because of this...
It's been 16 hours since I couldn't sleep..
Please help me.
I really don't understand...

Just in case, I deleted `/etc/ssh/host*` again
I thought the nic might be the same, so I switched it on and off with nmcil manually, but I also got a new MAC address.

Why not?
Please tell me now. I'm so curious
My physical strength is limited...

I want to solve this ssh problem and post multiple clusters.